# How to read Scope Identity in C# from executed Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, asp.net-3.5

I want to read `Scope_Identity` via output variable '@RoleID' from where I am assigning value of scope identity.

C#:

```
private static long createNewRoleInsert(ADB.Model.RolesModel roleModelObj, MSSQL sql)
{
       bool killConnection = Utils.getConnection(ref sql);

       long returnValue = 0;

       try
       {
           sql.SetSProc("[dbo].[p_Role_dfn_createNew]");
           sql.AddParam("@Title", roleModelObj.Title);
           sql.AddParam("@Description", roleModelObj.Description);
           sql.AddParam("@CreatedDate", roleModelObj.CreatedDate);

           var RoleID = sql.ExecuteNonQuery();

           if(RoleID!=0 && RoleID>0)
           {
               returnValue = RoleID;
           }
       }
       finally
       {
           if (killConnection)
               sql.Dispose();
       }

       return returnValue;
   }
```

Stored procedure:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[p_Role_dfn_createNew] 
    @Title nvarchar(250),
    @Description nvarchar(MAX) = NULL,
    @CreatedDate DateTime, 
    @RoleID bigInt OUTPUT
 AS
     SET NOCOUNT ON;
     SET XACT_ABORT ON  

     DECLARE @l_object AS SYSNAME = OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID),
             @l_error_msg AS NVARCHAR(2000)  

  BEGIN TRY
  BEGIN TRAN
    INSERT INTO [adb_TestDb].[dbo].[Role] ([Title], [Description], [CreatedDate])
    VALUES (@Title, @Description, @CreatedDate)

    COMMIT TRAN

    SET @RoleID = SCOPE_IDENTITY(); 

    RETURN @RoleID
 END TRY
 BEGIN CATCH
    -- rollback any open/uncomitted transactions
    IF XACT_STATE() IN ( -1, 1) ROLLBACK TRANSACTION            

    -- return an error containing the object, error number and error description
    SELECT @l_error_msg = 'Error number : ' + CAST(ERROR_NUMBER()AS VARCHAR) + '. ' + ERROR_MESSAGE()          
    RAISERROR (@l_error_msg,16,1)
 END CATCH
```

Comment: Is `MSSQL` an alias?

Comment: What class is it an alias for? i.e. what is the actual type of `sql`?

Comment: is class where database connection and configuration sets

Comment: So you are using `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand` within that class to actually execute the query?

Comment: Yes thats correct................

Comment: You don't add the parameter "@RoleID" to the command, this should be added with the right direction (Input or InputOutput). After you have executed this procedure the value of the parameter will have updated to your identity value. [Return values](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms174998.aspx) are generally used to return a status (success/failed etc) rather than to return actual data.

Comment: you are also missing a parameter that tells the direction of the output parameter that you are declaring for example if I want to return a value to a parameter named `returnValue` I need to do the following 
`SqlParameter returnValue = new SqlParameter();
returnValue.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
cmd.Parameters.Add(returnValue);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`

Answer (score 3):

The [`ExecuteNonQuery` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) doesn't return the return value from the procedure, it returns the number of rows affected.

To get the return value you would add a parameter with `ParameterDirection.ReturnValue`, however that won't safely get you the value in `@RoleID` as the return value from a procedure can't be a `bigint`, it's always an `int`.

As you already have `@RoleID` as an output parameter you should add parameter to the command to get the value. Example:

```
SqlParameter roleIdParam = new SqlParameter("@RoleID", SqlDbType.BigInt);
roleIdParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

cmd.Parameters.Add(roleIdParam);

// execute command

long roleId = (long)roleIdParam.Value;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an output parameter in C# to get the value of @RoleID from the stored procedure. Here's an example of that:

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("connectionString"))
{
    SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.CommandText = "dbo.p_Role_dfn_createNew";

    // add other parameters...

    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@RoleID", SqlDbType.BigInt))
            .Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    returnValue = (long)cmd.Parameters["@RoleID"].Value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the

```
RETURN @RoleID
```

to

```
SELECT @RoleID
```

or add the output parameter as explained in other answers